# The set of endomorphisms with their image contained in Jacobson radical is nilpotent ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory

I have a question:

> > For $A$ a finite dimensional algebra over an algebraically closed field $\mathbb K$ and a finitely generated $A$-module $M$, let $I(M)=\{f\in End_A(M)\mid Img(f)\subseteq MRad(A)\}$. Then $I(M)$ is a nilpotent ieal of $End_A(M)$.

The only thing that I can say is when $M$ is an indecomposable, which in that case $End_A(M)$ will form a two-sided ideal contained in $Nil(End_A(M)$ and in particular, an endomorphism of $M$ is either nilpotent or an isomorphism. And when its image is in $Rad(M)$ and since $Rad(M)$ is nilpotent so that will be nilpotent.

But in general I do not know how to show it!

Can someone let me know how to show it?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Many thanks! Yes sorry about that! I will edit it now!

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to show (**Step 0**) that $I(M)$ is an ideal first. But I leave that to you.

**Step 1**: Show that all $f \in I(M)$ are nilpotent. E.g. use that all $f$ are $A$-linear and that $Rad(A)$ is nilpotent. (Do you know that $Rad(A)$ is nilpotent? If yes, the proof for that probably goes along similar lines as this.)

**Step 2**: Show that $End_A(M)$ is a finite-dimensional $\Bbb K$-algebra. For the finite dimension, e.g. use that it is contained in $End_\Bbb K (M)$ and that $M$ is a finite-dimensional $\Bbb K$-vector space.

**Step 3**: Show in general that if $B$ is any finite-dimensional $\Bbb K$-algebra and $J$ an ideal of $B$ such that all elements of $J$ are nilpotent, then $J$ is a nilpotent ideal. E.g. you can use that $J$ is a finite dimensional $\Bbb K$-vector space, choose a basis, and use that in partcular all basis vectors are nilpotent.

**Step 4**: Apply the result of step 3 to $B=End_A(M)$ and $J=I(M)$.

(Note: Steps 2--4 can be avoided with more theory. Your ring is artinian hence noetherian, so by Levitzky's theorem even one-sided ideals consisting of nilpotent elements will be nilpotent. For a two-sided ideal, being finitely generated is enough, etc. There are many cases where one can conclude that an ideal consisting of nilpotent elements is nilpotent, and probably all of them apply to your ring.)

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! I think by using your comments it will not be too difficult to show that. Since it is easy to see that $I(M)$ is an ideal and the rest comes from your comments. Thanks! I will try to do it today after school.

Comment: No, sorry, I think I have problem in showing that $I(M)$ is an ideal. For to show that it is an Ideal, I need to show that for any $g\in End_A(M)$ we have $gI(M)\subseteq I(M)$. But for to show this we need to have $MRad(M)=Rad(M)?$ But do we have that?

Comment: What you have to show is: If the image of $f$ is in $M Rad(A)$, then for any $g \in End_A(M)$ the images of $f\circ g$ and of $g\circ f$ are also in $M Rad(A)$. The first is obvious, for the second use linearity.

Comment: Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Many thanks for your comments and for your answer again! But can I ask you please give me a complete answer with more details. As I am new in Jacobson radical, I want to see how it can be done. I also was thinking that we should have $Rad(End_A(M))\subseteq I(M)$. Can you explain more please? Thanks!

Comment: Which step exactly do you not understand or have trouble with? -- As to the second part of your comment, I am quite sure that $I(M) \subseteq Rad(End_A(M))$ (which under the conditions here (everything's finite dimensional, hence artinian) seems to be equivalent to the statement you want to prove), and maybe we have equality, but I don't see how the inclusion you state relates to the question.

Comment: Many thanks for your comment! I almost cannot understand the whole story for to write a relevant proof! I was thinking maybe it can be proved that $Rad(End_A(M)) = I(M)$ and then it will be nilpotent?

Comment: Also there is an almost analog statement for when $P:=M$ is a f.g. projective module. The difference is that there we intend to prove that $I(P)=Rad(End_A(P))$. And it has quite long and complicated proof which is related to small sub-modules.

Comment: I have tried to clarify my answer to your original post. If you now insist on proving **something different**, namely $I(M) = Rad(End_A(M))$, then you should ask that as a different question. I say again, I am not sure if $I(M) = Rad(End_A(M))$ is even true; and if you say a complicated proof is given, and *only in the special case that $M$ is projective*, then why do think there should be an *easier* proof for a *more general statement*?

Comment: Many thanks for your help! I will try to do it today!